# How to generate Spark Dataset aggregation long expers in loop?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I'm using Java Spark to stat a dataset.

I need to aggregate a dataset by many expers so the code is long and ugly. The expers have some common logics, can I generate the expers with loops? 
Here is the code sample, the real code have hundreds of lines with repeat codes:

```
Dataset<Row> res = ds.groupBy(ds.col("uid")).agg(functions.max(ds.col("create_time")).as("create_time"),functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("date_diff").$less$eq(30).and(ds.col("call_type").isin(callTypeOut)),
                    ds.col("duration"))).as("caller_call_time_1"),
                          functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("date_diff").$less$eq(60)
                            .and(ds.col("call_type").isin(callTypeOut)),
                    ds.col("duration"))).as("caller_call_time_2"),
            functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("date_diff").$less$eq(90)
                            .and(ds.col("call_type").isin(callTypeOut)),
                    ds.col("duration"))).as("caller_call_time_3"),
            functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("date_diff").$less$eq(120)
                            .and(ds.col("call_type").isin(callTypeOut)),
                    ds.col("duration"))).as("caller_call_time_4"),
            functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("date_diff").$less$eq(150)
                            .and(ds.col("call_type").isin(callTypeOut)),
                    ds.col("duration"))).as("caller_call_time_5"),
            functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("date_diff").$less$eq(180)
                            .and(ds.col("call_type").isin(callTypeOut)),
                    ds.col("duration"))).as("caller_call_time_6"))
```

I got the solution like this:

```
List<Column> exprs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i < 7; i ++ ) {
    exprs.add(functions.sum(functions.when(ds.col("date_diff").$less$eq(30*i)
                        .and(ds.col("call_type").isin(callTypeOut)),
                ds.col("duration"))).as("caller_call_time_"+Integer.toString(i));

}
Dataset<Row> res = ds.groupBy(ds.col("uid")).agg(functions.max(ds.col("create_time")).as("create_time"),
exprs.toArray(new Column[exprs.size()]));
```

Comment: Adding a show() and printSchema() or your data frames before and after the transformation really helps understanding your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Create a your dataframe (Dataset is a dataframe, in opposition to a dataset of anything else) with all the additional columns before and then perform the aggregation on the newly created columns. You could create the columns in a loop.
2. Build a UDAF (user-defined aggregation function) that will process your custom code, in Java.

Hope it helps...